# Is there a good Linux diagnotic tool to check laptop slowness?

Tags: laptop, ram, samsung

I bought a Samsung laptop (NP770Z7E) with Windows 10 but it was running too slow. So I installed a Linux OS but it still slow. It seems some problem with memory but I would to see if some tool can test and report the problem.

Comment: What is your exact model of laptop? If the preinstalled Windows was also slow, I strongly advise you to take it back where you bought it for a repair or replace, most reputable stores will give warranty.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @MarkKirby. But I bought it when I was in Europe. I no longer have a warranty.

Comment: OK you certainly meet minimum specs. If you think it is a memory issue try `sudo apt install memtester` To run it use `sudo memtester size iterations` where size is the amount of ram you have or wish to test and iterations is the number of times you wish the test to run (1 is fine).

Comment: The `hardinfo` tool may give some basic information about your system. There are some CPU benchmarks there. However, you should check also `syslog` for hardware / software problems.

Comment: Take a look at [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/). It might do what you want

Comment: Are you using an HDD or an SSD? There's a huge difference in performance. If you are still having trouble, I would suggest upgrading to a Solid State Drive.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to do all suggestions soon. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details which is where I'd start. Some OSes & releases do benefit from tweaking post install; but you need to start here by providing release details (Linux is the kernel all GNU/Linux use and is not very specific, after all Android uses the linux kernel too).